# Links to SDL Documentation and Community sites are broken

Tags: documentation

Recent updates on the SDL documentation and community sites are breaking some older existing links from tridion stack exchange.

When will SDL have redirects in place to fix this please?

For example in "Preview for ECL in RichText"

https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/17695/29

Link to SDL Docs "Styles Configuration"

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-D95860F7-15DF-4091-B24E-3539F7CB33C4

Just redirects to https://docs.sdl.com/home

"similar enchancement request about showing External Content previews to CMS users" https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/sdl_web_ideas/i/sdl-web-ideas/srq-6149---ecl-implement-gettemplatefragment

404 page not found

Comment: Redirects are in place already. Do you have examples of old URLs which are not resolved?

Comment: Please report these  broken links with SDL Support. This is supposed to work. See https://docs.sdl.com/806997/806975/documentation-center-2-0/will-hyperlinks-pointing-to-the-old-documentation-center-keep-working-/shortcut%2520urls